# Query to find the data set by matching the last characters of data set

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an application in which i am storing the record of cars
and i am making some filters to find the desire car.
I have created a filter to find a car by its starting matching characters

example

If there is a car named `Audi` and if i enter `au` then this returns me the **audi** car

```
db.collection('CARS')
    .orderBy('carName')
    .startAt('aud')  // Looking for aud___
    .endAt('aud\uf8ff')
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {...})
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

In this code i am finding the car by putting `car name` and the query find the data whose first characters matches with the **carName**

I want almost same in another query but if i type some value and the query gives me the car by matching its last characters

example

If i have a car **BMW** and If i Enter `MW` then the query returns me **BMW** car

How can i find the car by matching the last characters of `car Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no query operator in Firestore to search from the end of a string, only prefix searches are supported.

The easiest way to implement this use-case in Firestore would be to store the reversed string value, and search on that.

So create a field `reversedCarName` and store `idua` in there for the `audi`. With that in place, you can search from the end with:

```
db.collection('CARS')
    .orderBy('reversedCarName')
    .startAt('i')  // Looking for ___i
    .endAt('i\uf8ff')
```

Comment: Brilliant approach!